# Could not find client cert with dev name - web service

Tags: apex, webservices, ssl

I use an application which call an extern web service from Salesforce and I get an error during the call.

I get this message :

> Could not find client cert with dev name: '***' specified in clientCertName_x

This is my Apex class generated by WSDL2Apex :

```
//Generated by wsdl2apex

public class tempuriOrgAcnt {
    public class Add_element {
        public schemasDatacontractOrg200407MagellaAcnt.Account account;
        private String[] account_type_info = new String[]{'account','http://tempuri.org/',null,'0','1','true'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://tempuri.org/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'account'};
    }
    public class UpdateResponse_element {
        public String UpdateResult;
        private String[] UpdateResult_type_info = new String[]{'UpdateResult','http://tempuri.org/',null,'0','1','true'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://tempuri.org/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'UpdateResult'};
    }
    public class Delete_element {
        public Integer id;
        public String recordType;
        private String[] id_type_info = new String[]{'id','http://tempuri.org/',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] recordType_type_info = new String[]{'recordType','http://tempuri.org/',null,'0','1','true'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://tempuri.org/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'id','recordType'};
    }
    public class Update_element {
        public schemasDatacontractOrg200407MagellaAcnt.Account account;
        private String[] account_type_info = new String[]{'account','http://tempuri.org/',null,'0','1','true'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://tempuri.org/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'account'};
    }
    public class AddResponse_element {
        public String AddResult;
        private String[] AddResult_type_info = new String[]{'AddResult','http://tempuri.org/',null,'0','1','true'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://tempuri.org/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'AddResult'};
    }
    public class DeleteResponse_element {
        public String DeleteResult;
        private String[] DeleteResult_type_info = new String[]{'DeleteResult','http://tempuri.org/',null,'0','1','true'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://tempuri.org/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'DeleteResult'};
    }
    public class ClearUsernameBinding_IAccountService {
        public String endpoint_x = 'http://**.**.***.***:8080/SalesforceGateway/AccountService.svc';
        public Map<String,String> inputHttpHeaders_x;
        public Map<String,String> outputHttpHeaders_x;
        public String clientCertName_x;
        public String clientCert_x;
        public String clientCertPasswd_x;
        public Integer timeout_x;
        private String[] ns_map_type_info = new String[]{'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Magellan.Extranet.SalesforceGateway.DataContracts', 'schemasDatacontractOrg200407MagellaAcnt', 'http://tempuri.org/', 'tempuriOrgAcnt', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/', '// Account AsyncTempuriOrgAcnt schemasDa'};
        public String Add(schemasDatacontractOrg200407MagellaAcnt.Account account) {
            tempuriOrgAcnt.Add_element request_x = new tempuriOrgAcnt.Add_element();
            request_x.account = account;
            tempuriOrgAcnt.AddResponse_element response_x;
            Map<String, tempuriOrgAcnt.AddResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, tempuriOrgAcnt.AddResponse_element>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
              this,
              request_x,
              response_map_x,
              new String[]{endpoint_x,
              'http://tempuri.org/IAccountService/Add',
              'http://tempuri.org/',
              'Add',
              'http://tempuri.org/',
              'AddResponse',
              'tempuriOrgAcnt.AddResponse_element'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x.AddResult;
        }
        public String Delete_x(Integer id,String recordType) {
            tempuriOrgAcnt.Delete_element request_x = new tempuriOrgAcnt.Delete_element();
            request_x.id = id;
            request_x.recordType = recordType;
            tempuriOrgAcnt.DeleteResponse_element response_x;
            Map<String, tempuriOrgAcnt.DeleteResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, tempuriOrgAcnt.DeleteResponse_element>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
              this,
              request_x,
              response_map_x,
              new String[]{endpoint_x,
              'http://tempuri.org/IAccountService/Delete',
              'http://tempuri.org/',
              'Delete',
              'http://tempuri.org/',
              'DeleteResponse',
              'tempuriOrgAcnt.DeleteResponse_element'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x.DeleteResult;
        }
        public String Update_x(schemasDatacontractOrg200407MagellaAcnt.Account account) {
            tempuriOrgAcnt.Update_element request_x = new tempuriOrgAcnt.Update_element();
            request_x.account = account;
            tempuriOrgAcnt.UpdateResponse_element response_x;
            Map<String, tempuriOrgAcnt.UpdateResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, tempuriOrgAcnt.UpdateResponse_element>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
              this,
              request_x,
              response_map_x,
              new String[]{endpoint_x,
              'http://tempuri.org/IAccountService/Update',
              'http://tempuri.org/',
              'Update',
              'http://tempuri.org/',
              'UpdateResponse',
              'tempuriOrgAcnt.UpdateResponse_element'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x.UpdateResult;
        }
    }
}
```

I use the attributes "clientCertName_x" and "clientCertPasswd_x" (available in the Apex class) but they doesn't work and I don't understand why bacause the informatic system called from Salesforce doesn't require SSL certificate (what I read on internet), just an username and a password.

Anyone can help me please?

Regards
Aurélien

Comment: any solution work out for this issue? i also facing same issue

Answer (score 1):

> > Please check if the end-point set in Apex Class is correct and is listed in Remote Site Settings under Security Controls
> >     Also, you can generate a Self Signed Certificate from Certificate and Key Management under Security Controls, ask informatica to upload this at their server.

public class HTTPS_Class
{

```
    public String clientCertName_x;
    public String clientCert_x;             // not required with the new process
    public String clientCertPasswd_x; // not required with the new process
```

etc
}

I am calling this class in another Apex class

XYZ.HTTPS_Class p= new XYZ.HTTPS_Class();

```
     p.clientCertName_x = 'TestCERT'; // TestCERT is the certificate I generated in Salesforce and the same was installed on endpoint server
```

Comment: In fact, to call the webservice, I need an username and a password.

These parameters (clientCertName_x and clientCertPasswd_x) are for SSL certificates.

In the WSDL, there is no place to use username and password.

So, it's not my solution, I spoke with an other developer to use a SSL certificate.
I am waiting for him..

Regards
Aurélien